# Need a fixed and scrollable columns in a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make my first column as fixed coulmn in jQuery. 
I don't want to use any plugins except jquery plugin.

Please look at js fiddle,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw679/6/)

Here 2 tables are there, Just I want within one table.

```css
th,td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table1 {
    float: left;   
}        
.table2 {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;  
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px">    
    <table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th> make me fixed</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value number 1</td>     
        </tr>    
    </table>    

    <div class="table2">
       <table>
           <tr>
               <thead>
                   <th>make me scrollable eeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee</th>
               </thead>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> value number 2 </td>        
           </tr>    
       </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out how can I achieve this in a one table with fixed column and vertical and horizontal scroll.

Comment: you html markup is invalid you can't use thead in tr

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.table1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table2 {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px">

  <table class="table1">
    <tr>
      <thead>
        <th>make me fixed</th>
        <th class="table2">make me scrollable eeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee</th>
      </thead>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value number 1</td>
      <td class="table2">value number 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

It used table layout fixed, as well as setting the width for the table.

Comment: No. Scrollbar is inside the td. I want scrollbar outside the table. Not only Horizantal scrollbar, If vertical scrollbar also it should be in outside and the first column should be freeze

Comment: If you want to apply a scroll to the overall table, you are out of luck - you will have to use 2 tables and an overflowing div like your example. Why do you need 1 table? Maybe theres a different kind of solution if I understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If the first column can be fixed width, you can do something like this:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.table div {
    overflow: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    width: 800px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0;
}
.table {
    position: relative;
}
.table:after {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-right: 1px solid black
}
#head {
    width: 150px;
}
td, th {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
th {
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
}
td {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
tr {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <table>
            <col id="head" />
            <tr>
                <th>make me fixed fhfghghgfhggf</th>
                <td>make me scrollable eeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeee eeeeeeee</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>value number 1</th>
                <td>value number 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Drawbacks:

- Text in `th` cells can only be aligned to top.
- The `td` cells should be higher or equally high as the `th` cells.
- Requires extra divs

Comment: Thank you s much @Midas. This is what I want.